# Facebook SDK error. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match, anext time i can log in errorless

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

First describe you the weird behaviour i get , the first time i try to log i am redirected to facebook login page there i set my user and pass and then i am sent back to my site where i get the error stated above:

**Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.**

Then if i reload the page without the facebook code at url (http://www.whateverxxxxxx.com/creartemporada.php->>i erase from here on....) , and try to log in again i get perfectly log in , by clicking again de log me in link....

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once dirname(__FILE__). '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // optional

try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error 1: ' . $e->getMessage(); // HERE IS WHERE I AM FIRST THROWN OUT::::
    exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        // getting short-lived access token
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // setting default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    // redirect the user back to the same page if it has "code" GET variable
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        header('Location: creartemporada.php');
    }

    // getting basic info about user
    try {
        $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,email,id,picture.width(800).height(800),cover.width(300).height(175)');
        $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        session_destroy();
        // redirecting user back to app login page
        header("Location: ./");
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error 2: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // printing $profile array on the screen which holds the basic info about user

    $logOut = $helper->getLogoutUrl($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'], 'http://www.whateverxxxxxx.com/logout.php');
    echo "<a href='$logOut'>Log Out!</a>";


    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
    // replace your website URL same as added in the developers.facebook.com/apps e.g. if you used http instead of https and you used non-www version or www version of your website then you must add the same here
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://www.whateverxxxxxx.com/creartemporada.php', $permissions);
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}
```

Sorry to repeat the question i wanted to post my code for it is mismacht...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions here is the final code:

Basically i added 
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state'];

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once dirname(__FILE__). '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'xxxxx',
    'app_secret' => 'xxxxxx',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state'];

$permissions = ['email']; // optional

try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error 1: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        // getting short-lived access token
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // setting default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    // redirect the user back to the same page if it has "code" GET variable
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        header('Location: creartemporada.php');
    }

    // getting basic info about user
    try {
        $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,email,id,picture.width(800).height(800),cover.width(300).height(175)');
        $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        session_destroy();
        // redirecting user back to app login page
        header("Location: ./");
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error 2: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // printing $profile array on the screen which holds the basic info about user

    $logOut = $helper->getLogoutUrl($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'], 'http://www.xxxxwhatever.com/logout.php');
    echo "<a href='$logOut'>Log Out!</a>";


    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
    // replace your website URL same as added in the developers.facebook.com/apps e.g. if you used http instead of https and you used non-www version or www version of your website then you must add the same here

    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://www.xxxxwhatever.com/creartemporada.php', $permissions);

    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}
```